# Обработка ошибок, возникающих в конструкторе

Tags: c++, конструктор

Допустим, есть класс с конструктором с параметрами, внутри которого предусмотрена проверка на корректность аргументов. И вот вопрос: а как обработать возникшую в конструкторе ошибку? Я в первую очередь подумал генерировать исключения и взять объявление объекта класса в блок `try`, но тут же столкнулся с проблемой, что объект-то создается, исключения перехватываются, но вот объект за пределами блока `try` не виден. Тогда как вообще правильно обрабатывать ошибки, возникшие в конструкторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если аргументы некорректны, то объект класса не может быть создан и следует просто вызвать исключение через `throw`. Обработкой этого исключения должен заниматься код, который инициировал попытку создания объекта с ошибочными аргументами.

В другом случае в этой ситуации можно было бы создать объект с аргументами по умолчанию, которые явно будут правильными. Но это лишь завуалирует проблему ошибочных аргументов, что не очень хорошо.

Comment: т.е. просто генерировать исключение, но никак не стараться его перехватывать?

Comment: @WenSiL если проблему можно решить по месту (прямо в конструкторе), то никакие исключения не нужны вовсе. Исключение позволяет перенести обработку ошибки на тот уровень, где ясно, что с этой ошибкой делать.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Общий подход в том, чтобы объявить переменную до блока `try`, попробовать инициализировать внутри блока и использовать после.

Comment: т.е. получается, что конструктор с параметрами нет большого смысла создавать? Будет проще и правильнее написать метод, который будет выполнять ровно те же самые функции?